# Get specific fields from Kendo locales js files

Tags: angular, localization, kendo-ui-angular2

Kendo Internationalization library provide a huge amount of JS files with the specific information of each country culture. I'm using its `IntlService` and `TranslateService` to handle the language in the system, but now I need to get specific information from these files, like the currency and decimal separator for the current language and available languages.

These files are located in `@progress/kendo-angular-intl/locales` and the json is encapsulated inside a function called `setData()`. I don't want to copy the information of them (easy path), but reuse them in order to automatize the addition of a new language for example. At last, I searched if kendo already implements a service that provides the option to get specific fields of these files, but there is not.

So, my question is: How can I get information from these files? Does it exist a service for that purpose or I have to implement it by myself?

I show an example of one of the files:

```
import { setData } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';
setData({
    name: "es-CL",
    identity: {
        language: "es",
        territory: "CL"
    },
    territory: "CL",
    numbers: {
        symbols: {
            decimal: ",",
            group: ".",
            list: ";",
            percentSign: "%",
            plusSign: "+",
            minusSign: "-",
            exponential: "E",
            superscriptingExponent: "×",
            perMille: "‰",
            infinity: "∞",
            nan: "NaN",
            timeSeparator: ":"
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number symbols you just need to import in your component

```
import { numberSymbols } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';
```

and then access its values with the function `numberSymbols` using the local Id you need. Example: to get the `decimal` with `es-CL`:

```
 numberSymbols('es-CL').decimal
```

returns `,` as expected.

I guess the other values have equivalent functions to access them. You can check [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/globalization/internationalization/api/IntlService/#toc-numbersymbols) if you need it.